# Prob. 7, Chap. 3 in Baby Rudin: If $a_n \geq 0$, then how does convergence of $\sum a_n$ imply convergence of $\sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Here's Prob. 7 in the Exercises of Chapter 3 in the book *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Walter Rudin, 3rd edition:

> Prove that the convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies the convergence of $$ \sum \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$$ if $a_n \geq 0$.

How to show this? I have no clue! Can anybody here please be of any help?

Is this result a special case (or application) of a more general result about infinite series?

Answer (score 3):

By the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality),
$$
\sum\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}n\le\biggl(\sum a_n\biggr)^{1/2}\biggl(\sum\frac1{n^2}\biggr)^{1/2}.
$$

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem

Comment: @MarkMcClure I do not think that is fair to downvote for this reason. Post a better answer instead of a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

We need to establish that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ is convergent where it is given that the series of non-negative terms $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent.

here we see that 
$\sum a_n$ is convergent implies $\sum a_n^2$ is also convergent. Now $\sum a_n^2 +\sum \frac{1}{n^2}=\sum (a_n^2+\frac{1}{n^2})\geq \sum 2\sqrt{a_n^2\cdot \frac{1}{n^2}}=2\sum \frac{a_n}{n}$.

The LHS of this inequality is bounded above. hence the proof.

Comment: how do we know that, for a series $\sum a_n$ of non-negative terms, the convergence of $\sum a_n$ implies the convergence of $\sum a_n^2$?

Comment: Hint: Let $\sum x_n, \sum y_n$ be two series of non-negative real numbers that are convergent. Then $\sum x_n y_n$ is also a series of non-negative real number which is convergent too.

Comment: can you please also supply a proof of this same result?